# hashtages between quotation marks

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I am working on this little code. I managed to make it work with the double quotation mark on one side but not on the other:

`/(?<!\S)#([0-9\p{L}]+)+(?=[\s,!?.\n][^"]|$)/`

Here's what I mean: https://regex101.com/r/yN4tJ6/307

The last `" #action`  should not be converting into a hashtag. How do I add this function to the code above?

Comment: Is you string html code? Are you trying to avoid html attributes?

Comment: Are you looking to exclude matching pounds between double quotes or outside double quotes. Either way requires a balanced approach  and is best served using the `\G` construct (in your case), or a callback matching all quotes content, then push into an array any pounds found in that string. Either way is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression seems to work:

```
(?<!\S)(?<!".)#([0-9\p{L}]+)+(?=[\s,!?.\n][^"]|$)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/t9kbyd/1)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might wanted to design an expression similar to:

```
(?<!"\s)#([0-9\p{L}]+)(?=[\s,!?.\n][^"]|$)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vBfK3v/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/vBfK3v/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?<!"\s)#([0-9\p{L}]+)(?=[\s,!?.\n][^"]|$)/m';
$str = 'I enjoy #action movies! #Action
movies are #cool.

Color #000000;  #ffffff; work fine

<div style=" #something "> - works

#action " - works

" #action  - doesn\'t work


';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: However, it stops working when the double quotes touch the hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current pattern, which almost works, is that you would need a variable width lookbehind to correctly check for the presence/absence of a double quote *before* each hashtag.  The approach I took was to use `preg_match_all` with a pattern which just consumes enough information to make a decision as to whether a hashtag is a match or not.  Consider the following script:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|[^"]\s+)(#[0-9\p{L}]+)[.;,!?]?(?=$|\s+[^"])/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

 Array
(
    [0] => #action
    [1] => #Action
    [2] => #cool
    [3] => #000000
    [4] => #ffffff
)
```

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
(?:^|[^"]\s+)   match the start of the input, OR
                a single non quote character, followed by one or more whitespaces
(#[0-9\p{L}]+)  then match and capture a hashtag
[.;,!?]?        followed by an optional punctuation character
(?=$|\s+[^"])   finally lookahead and assert either the end of the input, OR
                one or more whitespaces followed by a single non quote character
```

Note that while we do match some content which we don't really want, that doesn't matter, because the first capture group only contains the hashtag.

Comment: It fails to skip colors i.e. #ffffff;

Comment: How do we know what is and what is not a hashtag?

Comment: It easy: `#something` is a hashtag. `"#something"` or `" #something "` is not. `#something;` is not. The idea is it shouldn't mess up your HTML codes.